# mod rewrite on apache on virtualhost to point to jboss

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy, jboss, mod-proxy-ajp

I set my apache server with ajp to connect to my jboss server and it is working fine. But when I go to my domain http://mydomain.com, I see the jboss root page. I was wondering if I could use mod rewrite so when they type http://mydomain.com it gets redirected to http://mydomain.com/myapp. I just enable modwrite, but I tried to set it on my virtualost, and configtest send me an error when I was trying to set RewriteRule inside virtualhost.. Looking at the rule RewriteRule goes on the .htaccess.
I have also other domains and apps on that machine so I dont want to set a global rule..

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPassMatch ^/(app|app2|app3)(.*) ajp://localhost:8009/$1$2 ttl=120 ping=1
</VirtualHost>
```

What this snippet does is to match the incoming request against some known patterns and use the capabilities of `mod_proxy` and `mod_proxy_ajp` to pass that request to the backend, using backreferences (`$1` and `$2`).

This way, you can use a `VirtualHost` entry to publish every applications hosted in the backend container, provided it can use an AJP listener.

Check the [apache online docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for a detailed explanation on the rest of the parameters (`ttl` and `ping`)